# Getting textbox values from a CefSharp browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I've got a winforms app that has a ChromiumWebBrowser control and some basic windows controls. I want to be able to click a button, call javascript to get the value of a textbox in the browser, and copy the returned value to a textbox in the winforms app. Here is my code:

```
string script = "(function() {return document.getElementById('Email');})();";

string returnValue = "";

var task = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script, new { });

await task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (!t.IsFaulted)
        {
            var response = t.Result;
            if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
            {
                returnValue = (string)response.Result;
            }
        }
    });

txtTarget.Text = returnValue;
```

The result that comes back however is just "{ }". I've loaded the same web page in Chrome and executed the same javascript in the dev tools and I get the textbox value as expected.

The demo I looked at had sample code, simply "return 1+1;", and when I tried that I was getting the value "2" returned instead of "{ }". Interestingly, when I tried

```
string script = "(function() {return 'hello';})()";
```

I was still getting "{ }", almost as though this doesn't work with strings.

I've been scratching my head at this for a while and haven't been able to figure out how to solve this. Am I making a very basic syntax error or is there something more complicated going on?

Comment: Your probably executing your script too early, see the general usage guide for details.

Comment: The script is executed when a button is clicked, so it doesn't make sense that the page couldn't be loaded if I can wait as long as I want

Answer (score 6):

So I think I've figured it out:

```
string script = "(function() {return document.getElementById('Email').value;})();";
string returnValue = "";

var task = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);

await task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (!t.IsFaulted)
    {
        var response = t.Result;

        if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
        {
            returnValue = response.Result.ToString();
        }
    }
});  

txtTarget.Text = returnValue;
```

Removing the args object from EvaluateScriptAsync seemed to fix the issue. Not sure what the problem was - perhaps it was trying to run the javascript function with an empty args object when it shouldn't take any parameters?

Either way, it's resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void SetElementValueById(ChromiumWebBrowser myCwb, string eltId, string setValue)
    {         
        string script = string.Format("(function() {{document.getElementById('{0}').value='{1}';}})()", eltId, setValue);
        myCwb.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);            
    }

    public string GetElementValueById(ChromiumWebBrowser myCwb, string eltId)
    {        
        string script = string.Format("(function() {{return document.getElementById('{0}').value;}})();",
             eltId);
        JavascriptResponse jr = myCwb.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).Result;
        return jr.Result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `EvaluateScriptAsync` returns a `Task`, you must `await` or use `ContinueWith` to reliably obtain the result. This code will be totally unreliable.

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: @amaitland -- it is not "task async" -- It returns void, not `Task`. It is "async" as is "Begin...", "End..." TPL pattern. How he has it is how it should be.

Comment: @Andy EvaluateScriptAsync returns a Task,  where as ExecuteScriptAsync is a void method.  They are similarly named, very different behaviour. EvaluateScriptAsync should be used asynchronously, blocking on Result is not supported. The complexity of the Chromium threading model make it very easy to deadlock if you call on the incorrect thread.

Comment: @amaitland -- i didn't see the 2nd method. was only looking at the first. I stand corrected.